# Routing requests to multiple backend servers Dropwizard and Elasticsearch

Tags: http, nginx, elasticsearch, frontend, dropwizard

I have to backend servers :

1. A dropwizard server that serves as a mainly application server. This server is used by the frontend for all operations except searching.
2. An elasticsearch server feeded by the dropwizard server which serves the frontend for all search queries.

Knowing that dropwizard is running on port 8080  and elasticsearch on port 9200, is There any strategy to have a single frontend (nginx for example or apache) that can be used to route search request to elasticsearch and non search request to dropwizard (adding extra headers to distinguish search request or using a different path in the url for search request)?

I Am open to any suggestion or configuration,

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nginx configurations

you can proxy them by their own ports:

```
server {
  listen 8080;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://dropwizard-host:8080/;
  }
}

server {
  listen 9200;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://elasticsearch-host:9200/;
  }
}
```

Or have them mapped to the same port with different path:

```
server {
  listen 80;

  location /dropwizard {
    proxy_pass http://dropwizard-host:8080/;
  }

  location /elasticsearch {
    proxy_pass http://elasticsearch-host:9200/;
  }
}
```